# Why this caused tomcat show jsp source instead of actually rendering the html?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

I was touching Spring MVC after many years and I started with [this example](https://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/).

I tried tuts step by step and ran it. However when I ran it, it showed source of `index.jsp` instead of rendering it.

So I went on cross checking contents of various files and I realized that my index.jsp has below at the starting, while the tut's doesn't:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

I recalled that these were the lines auto generated by the eclipse when I created jsp pages. I didnt delete them as I thought these must be valid. Now I am thinking, why this made my example fail? (Removing them made index.jsp render appropriately.)

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a wrong order in your statements. An Example for the beginning of a JSP follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ page pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
...
```